# How can I make a div and its text disappear when window gets resized?

Tags: css, html, position

I have a big container (over 2400 px wide) with 2 DIVs in it (see pictures attached). When the window gets resized or the computer's supported resolution is low, **only DIV 1 should be visible, DIV 2 then should disappear**.

I tried that:

```
@media all and (max-width: 1800px) {
  #DIV2 { display: none; }
}
```

and it worked, of course, but I want the text in DIV2 stay at its position and not shift to the left, when the window gets resized – even if it's just a few pixels. I played around with **position** properties and **margins**, but it didn't work. How can I fix the text?

Thanks in advance!

[image: full resolution/big window]

[image: small resolution/small window]

Comment: Wait, so why is the info about `div2` dissapearing at higher resolutions even relevant?

Comment: it's just extra artwork that *must* be cut when the resolution is low. it's build like a big landscape picture that shows the most at a high resolution. So the DIV1 is the part with the most important information.

But I will make another version for low resolutions I decided.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `border:none` for this issue instead of `display:none` :

```
@media all and (max-width: 1800px) {
  #DIV2 { border: none; }
}
```

Comment: nope, that makes it worse, the text will be shifted to left again, again and again ...